# Passing variables in python from radio buttons

Tags: scripting, maya

I want to set values depends on the selected radio button and to use that values in other function. 
Whatever i try, i always get the same answer

## NameError: global name 'tX' is not defined #

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

winID='MSDKID'

def init(*args):
    print tX
    print tY
    print tZ
    print rX
    print rY
    print rZ    
    return 

def prozor():

    if cmds.window(winID, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(winID);
    cmds.window()
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True, rowSpacing=10 )
    cmds.button(label = "Init")
    cmds.button(label = "MirrorSDK",command=init)
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    cmds.setParent( '..' )

    cmds.frameLayout( label='Position' )
    cmds.columnLayout()
    collection2 = cmds.radioCollection()
    RButton0 = cmds.radioButton( label='Behavior' )
    RButton1 = cmds.radioButton( label='Orientation' )
    cmds.button(l='Apply', command = partial(script,RButton0,RButton1,))
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    cmds.setParent( '..' ) 
    print script(RButton0,RButton1)
    cmds.showWindow()

def script(RButton0,RButton1,*_cb_val):
    X = 0
    rb0 = cmds.radioButton(RButton0, q = True, sl = True)
    rb1 = cmds.radioButton(RButton1,q = True, sl = True)
    if (rb0 == True):
        tX = -1
        tY = -1
        tZ = -1

        rX = 1
        rY = 1
        rZ = 1

    if (rb1 == True):
        tX = -1
        tY = 1
        tZ = 1 
        rX = 1
        rY = -1
        rZ = -1
        return tX,tY,tZ,rX,rY,rZ        

prozor()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are defining in `script()` are local to that function. The other functions don't see them.

If you need multiple UI elements to share data, you'll  probably need to create a class to let them share variables.  Some reference [here](http://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet) and [here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3292-maya-python-UI-acessing-controls-from-external-functions)